# Phonegap Accelerometer y value to degrees

Tags: javascript, cordova, accelerometer

Phonegap accelerometer seems to return y values as below:

```
// +10 y axis = straight up = 0/360 deg
// -10 y axis = straight down = 180 deg
// flat y axis = 90/270 deg
```

My question is, how do I convert this y axis to the given degrees?

Also, as it's phonegap, I'm assuming these values are the same for all devices. if anyone knows otherwise please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
deg = acceleration.y / 10 * 90;
```

I think that worked for me when I was doing something similar.