# How do I work out device tilt using phonegap Accelerometer API

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm currently building an app in PhoneGap/Cordova to measure the angle of a slope using the device as a kind of spirit level.  As such I need to get the slope angle in degrees from the readings taken from the accelerometer, using the accelerometer api from PhoneGap.

Below is the code in the onSuccess function of the Acceleration which is passed Acc which is the acceleration of the device.

```
function onSuccess(acc) {

// Using x y and z from accelerometer, calculate x and y angles

var x_val, y_val, z_val, result;
var x2, y2, z2; //24 bit

// Lets get the deviations from our baseline
x_val = parseFloat(acc.x);
y_val = parseFloat(acc.y);
z_val = parseFloat(acc.z) - 9.8;

// Work out the squares 
x2 = (x_val*x_val);
y2 = (y_val*y_val);
z2 = (z_val*z_val);

//X Axis
result=Math.sqrt(y2+z2);
result=x_val/result;
accel_angle_x = Math.atan(result);

//Y Axis
result=Math.sqrt(x2+z2);
result=y_val/result;
accel_angle_y = Math.atan(result);

el.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acc.x + ' ' + accel_angle_x + 'deg <br />' +
                        'Acceleration Y: ' + acc.y  + ' ' + accel_angle_y + 'deg <br />' +
                        'Acceleration Z: ' + acc.z + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '      + acc.timestamp + '<br />';

}
```

The code is adapted from a Java example found at http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/accelerometer-info

The baselines for x y z are assumed to be 0, 0, 9.8 respectively.

The output I get from the code above just appears to be nonsense, it certainly does not appear to be an angle of the slope.

How can I make the function output the device tilt in degrees ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
deg = acceleration.y / 10 * 90;
```

Have a look [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758043/phonegap-accelerometer-y-value-to-degrees)  [Link 2](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/13667)

Comment: Thanks AtanuCSE, I'll give that a go.  That kind of calculation was kinda like my initial approach but then I read the following on http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/accelerometer-info
"Note also, that the output from accelerometers is not linear but is a sinewave, so you cannot take the direct output as a proportional representation of an angle of tilt based on gravity."